# sqlite: does dropping a database table delete the data?

Tags: sqlite

I used "drop table" sql command to delete a table from my database.
Strangely, the size of the db file does not change since then, even though I have been adding and deleting data from it.

Does that mean the dropped table is never erased, and if new table is created the new table just overwrite wherever the dropped table was located?

I am using windows 7 64 bits and sqlite3, if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQLite marks the space in the file as free and reuses it as needed.
You can execute VACUUM command to shrink the file (this may be slow).